# Syntax error on token string

Tags: java, android

I tried to put this code in but theres an error in it, what should be done?
Isit because i put public string inside onStart()?

`MediaPlayer playMusic;`

```
@Override

protected void onStart() {

    public String getIpAddr() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();


           WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
           WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
           int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();

           String ipString = String.format(
           "%d.%d.%d.%d",
           (ip & 0xff),
           (ip >> 8 & 0xff),
           (ip >> 16 & 0xff),
           (ip >> 24 & 0xff));

           return ipString;



    //for(int array;array < 256;array++)
    //try {

        //if("192.168.150.16".equals(WIFI_SERVICE))
    }

}
```

should i create a new class?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    getIpAddr();
    super.onStart();
}

public String getIpAddr() 
{

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();

    String ipString = String.format(
            "%d.%d.%d.%d",
            (ip & 0xff),
            (ip >> 8 & 0xff),
            (ip >> 16 & 0xff),
            (ip >> 24 & 0xff));

    return ipString;



    //for(int array;array < 256;array++)
    //try {

    //if("192.168.150.16".equals(WIFI_SERVICE))
}
```

Comment: is the position for `public string getipAddr` and `public void onStart` as in, which one comes first matters?

Comment: position of methods doesn't matter.First onCreate method is executed after that onstart() method will be execute [Refer this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: do you know any codes to see whether this codes are successful, that i can be seen in the console? should i put `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`?